# Build VS Code with classic executable, separate app on taskbar and my own icon

Tags: visual-studio-code, build, customization

How could I build my own instance VS Code with classic executable, separate app on taskbar and my own icon?

I have tried build VSCode but I can't create normal exe like is Code.exe. For more I have tried replaced several images and icons with mine but always was replacing with default.

I have tried build also VSCodium - there was created VSCodium.exe but with default icons in taskbar and when I run installed VSCodium from Chocolatey etc., on taskbar are both mixed to one, even both was builded on different PC and both have different path, with different .exe with different version (1.63.1 (user setup) for installed vs 1.63.2 for my own builded) but with same size. Also I wasn't be able to change icon for taskbar.

Thanks for all advices